# Symfony 1.4 Backend app for admin fail on Prod environment

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, admin

I have a perfectly working admin backend on my dev environment but it fails miserably on the prod environment. Specifically a bunch of problems arise :

1. It is unable to read the symfony/web/sf/ directory hence not loading the required images though it states that a project has been successfully created. This however is not the case with the frontend leading me to believe that the problem is more sinister than what meets the eye.
2. Though it loads the admin pages, the css is not loaded, even though admin.css is present in the web/css directory.

I did an inspect element and the problem seems to be this, instead of routing to
/web/css or /sfDoctrinePlugin or /web/js
it prefixes the name of the app [controlcenter in my case] to everything, essentially rendering the HTML as: 
href =  "/controlcenter/web/css" or href = "/controlcenter/js" or href = "/controlcenter/js" . And this does not happen at all on my dev environment and things render the way they do.

Fixits anyone?

Comment: Is the .htaccess file the one that came with symfony? What about your vhost? How is it configured?

Comment: this is naturally irrelevant since my frontend app works fine, but the backend routing is wrong

Comment: how did you call your backend app? backend.php/ ? backend_dev.php/ ?

Comment: on the dev environ: controlcenter_dev.php/model and on the prod controlcenter/model

Comment: it renders itself, the only issue being that it is prefixing controlcenter to everything before it... for instance js files become controlcenter/js instead of just /js or stylesheets controlcenter/css and not /css ....on the dev environment this issue does not exist though

Answer (score 1):

This was completely ridiculous of me to post this. I was simply trying to go to controlcenter/module which basically translates to backend/module for most people.

The index file in this case is controlcenter.php, and upon accessing that, I get the website to render the way it ought to. Sorry for the confusion people. Hopefully someone drops in by and sees the answer for themselves.

I should set up defaults in my routing.yml so that it automatically redirects without me having to type controlcenter.php 
Thanks